# How Do I Add a Class to a CodeIgniter Anchor

Tags: css, codeigniter

I have the following:

```
'.anchor('','Home').'
```

and I want to add the following CSS class to it:

```
class="top_parent"
```

This is so that when it's rendered in the browser, the code will look something like the following:

```
<a href="#" class="top_parent">Home</a>
```

Thanks in advance, and any help is greatly appreciated.

--

Tom

Comment: StackOverflow was one of several avenues I started looking down. It turned out that you answered before I goto the correct information in CI documentation. I had a question, might as well share it as I try to find the answer. As stackoverflow states: "... it is welcome here. No question is too trivial or too "newbie"." .... (even if you haven't read the book...)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
anchor('#', 'Home', array('class' => 'top_parent'));
```

Answer (score 5):

The Codeignitor function is defined as such:

```
function anchor($uri = '', $title = '', $attributes = '')
```

I would try sending an array with a class key and value first.

These functions are found inside the \system\helpers\ folder.

Comment: boy all that time i spend finding the function and two very talented people had answered the question already. Oh well - my answer is here to stay.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify an associative array of attributes for your Anchor. So, for example:

anchor('', 'Home', array('class' => 'top_parent'));

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$myClass = array('class' => 'top_parent');

echo anchor('#', 'Home', $myClass);
```

Hope it will be clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be used like this:

```
<?php echo anchor('#', 'Home', 'class="top_parent"' ); ?>
```

And if you want extra attributes like title for example, it can be done like this:

```
<?php echo anchor('#', 'Home', 'class="top_parent" title="Home"' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> From Codeigniter's [manual](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html):
>
> **anchor()** has three optional parameters:

```
anchor(uri segments, text, attributes)
```

Simple example:

```
anchor(url,text,array('class'=>'class1'));
```

Answer (score -2):

For example if you have a css **class** called `btn`, and a button called submit, to submit (call a submit controller class called sub) 
You can do it this way

```
<?php echo anchor('sub', 'submit', 'class="btn" ');? >
```